# How to Reduce load on cassandra server so to avoid NoHostAvailable Exceptions

Tags: cassandra

I  am running 5 node apache cassandra cluster(3.11.4), given 48 GB RAM , 12 GB heap memory and  6 vcpus per each node. I can see a lot of load (18 GB)on the cassandra server nodes even when there is no data processing in cassandra servers.I can a lot of GC pauses, because of which I can see "NoHostAvailable" exceptions when I try to push data to cassandra.

Please suggest me how to reduce this load and how can I avoid connection failures "NoHostAvailable".

```
ID                     : a65c8072-636a-480d-8774-2c5704361bec
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : true
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 18.07 GiB
Generation No          : 1576158587
Uptime (seconds)       : 205965
Heap Memory (MB)       : 3729.16 / 11980.81
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 12.81
Data Center            : dc1
Rack                   : rack1
Exceptions             : 21
Key Cache              : entries 2704, size 5.59 MiB, capacity 100 MiB, 1966 hits, 4715 requests, 0.417 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit 
rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 50 MiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Chunk Cache            : entries 25, size 1.56 MiB, capacity 480 MiB, 4207149 misses, 4342386 requests, 0.031 recent hit rate, NaN microseconds miss latency
Percent Repaired       : 34.58708788430304%
Token                  : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 48Gb RAM I recommend to get to at least cheap of 16Gb or 20. Make sure that you are using G1 GC (default in Java 8).

But NoHostAvailable may depend on the consistency level that you are using, and other factors..

On other side, you may consider to throttle your application  - sometimes pushing slower may lead to better throughput.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response , can you please suggest how to reduce load (18 gb) on the node .

Comment: 18Gb load per node is usually nothing to care about. Usually it should just you fit into memory.  But usually problems are around queries, big partitions, etc.